# Find how many characters of a certain type in a string

Tags: javascript

I have the following string variable:

```
var text = "one ensjcvndfpwenv";
```

How can I find, **through pure Javascript** how many `e` characters are there in the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though i would call it a hack but can work

```
var count = text.split("e").length - 1;
```

Comment: What will happen if there's an `e` at the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: I believe it will give the correct result. Do you have any queries/update?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex as follows:

```
var matches = text.match(/e/g);
var cnt = matches && matches.length || 0;
```

Comment: var matches = text.match(/e/g); ;)

Comment: Damn it, you are right!! Fixed, thank you. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the split method, there is no real easy way to ultimately do it without counting up the instances in pure JavaScript (no regex involved).

```
function findNumberOfCertainCharacters(character, searchString){
    var searchStringLength = searchString.length, counter = 0;

  for(var ii = 0 ; ii < searchStringLength; ii++){
     if(searchString[ii] === character){counter ++;}
  }

  return counter; 
}
```

Personally, I think the other methods are better, but this is the pure JavaScript way of doing it without creating a new string array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the indexOf() method to count the occurrence

var pos = 0;
  var occ = -1;
  var i = -1;
  var text = "one ensjcvndfpwenv";

while (pos != -1) 
{
    pos = graf.indexOf("e", i + 1);
    occ += 1;
    i = pos;
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this:

```
var string = "on nsjcvndfpwnv";
var match = string.match(/e/g);
var count = match ? match.length : 0;
```

Comment: Match can return null. Look at the responses above. ;-)

Comment: I think some things doesn't need to be explained, but to stay clean... ;)

Comment: Now it works, but you run the match twice and this is not so optimized an approach. :-P